# ngx-toastr in Angular 9 App with container in one child component

Tags: angular9, ngx-toastr

I am using ngx-toastr to display notification messages. but I want to display the message only in one child component (and the width should be adjusted according to the width of the child component). when the user navigates to another route, it should not be visible.

i tried https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#put-toasts-in-your-own-container ,but not working.

Please help.